# Apply different styles by the result of computed styles

Tags: css

How can I apply different styles by the result of computed styles?

This can be done via JavaScript, but I'm finding a CSS only solution.

e.g.

```css
body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Segoe UI; }
```

In above case, I would like to apply `letter-spacing: -0.5px` only for `Arial`, not others.

Comment: I don't think there's a native css way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Use this attr:
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang.en
(I guess CSS can't figure out text's fonts types.
You need to use scss(sass) or JS.)

```css
:lang(ta)   {
    font-family: Latha, "Tamil MN", serif;
    font-size: 120%;
    }
```

Comment: My problem was not a language related issue.  Could you let me know how to do only in SCSS?